# Netbeans - Custom new project

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, new-project

How do I add a custom project in Netbeans' `New Project -> Choose Project -> Categories` menu? I'm talking about project similar to `Java -> Java App`, but with custom classes.

Comment: I don't get what you mean with 'custom classes', an external library or a project with excisting sources?

Comment: Project with existing sources and included JDK. This simple. It's like Sample Project. But I can't find where those are stored or how to add one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Hope the [NetBeans Project Type Module Tutorial](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-projecttype.html) is what you're looking for

Comment: This is exaggerated way I guess. Wrote more accurate description of what I want to get, as question comment.